# Как подключить две версии одной библиотеки в Any CPU

Tags: c#, wpf

одна версия под x64, другая под 32. имя библиотек совпадает
Как правильно или более удобно их можно обе подключить?

дополнение:
посмотрел по предложенной ссылке в ответе.
сделал новое консольное приложение, добавил согласно материалу ссылку на одну из версий библиотеки, после этого скопировал файл проекта в другую папку и открыл в визуал студии для редактирования.
Файл до редактирования:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7A0D5B4B-293F-44C3-96BF-4A0AB01F2DFF}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>TestBd4</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TestBd4</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Desktop\библиотеки\crypt\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

согласно материалу по [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019#example-referencing-x86-and-x64-assemblies-and-dlls)  - ... Используйте четыре элемента ItemGroup со всеми сочетаниями параметров, как показано далее.

отредактировал и получил файл с содержанием:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7A0D5B4B-293F-44C3-96BF-4A0AB01F2DFF}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>TestBd4</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TestBd4</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Desktop\библиотеки\crypt\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Desktop\библиотеки\crypt\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Desktop\библиотеки\crypt\Win32\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Desktop\библиотеки\crypt\Win32\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

после чего заменяю файл проекта в папке с приложением и получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что сделано не правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

1. Добавляем ссылку на библиотеку.
2. У ссылки ставим **Копировать локально** = False
3. Делаем так, чтобы две версии библиотеки лежали в подкаталогах x86 и x64 выходного каталога. Т.е. структура должна быть такой:

MyProject\MyProject.csproj
MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.dll
MyProject\bin\Debug\x86\MyLib.dll
MyProject\bin\Debug\x64\MyLib.dll

4. В коде делаем следующее:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class MyClass
    {
        static MyClass()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        }

        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

            string basepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
                basepath = Path.Combine(basepath, "x64");
            else
                basepath = Path.Combine(basepath, "x86");
                        
            Assembly ret = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(basepath, name.Name + ".dll"));
            return ret;
        }

        public static void Method()
        {
            //работа с библиотекой
        }
    }    
}
```

Суть способа в том, чтобы перехватить событие разрешения сборки и подсунуть разную версию в зависимости от разрядности. **Обязательное условие** - чтобы непосредственно в каталоге с программой не было никакой версии MyLib.dll, т.е. стандартный алгоритм разрешения должен завершиться с ошибкой. Иначе наш обработчик не запустится. Обработчик должен быть прицеплен до объявления любой переменной из библиотеки, поэтому он помещен в статическом конструкторе. Таким образом это можно заставить работать с AnyCPU.

Comment: да, так работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Начиная с версии 1.0.80.0 это все есть непосредственно в самой System.Data.SQLite. Почитайте об этом в [документации](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). А тут [пошаговое руководство](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245310/using-any-cpu-from-multiple-files-x64-x86/52245480#52245480)

Comment: это не оригинальная System.Data.SQLite , это sqlcrypt и он был поставлен как две версии под х86 и х64

Answer (score 3):

Можно прописать соответствующие `Conditions` для `ItemGroup` в файле вашего проекта:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
    <HintPath>..\path\x64\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
    <HintPath>..\path\x86\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Подробнее по [ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019#example-referencing-x86-and-x64-assemblies-and-dlls)

Comment: попробовал сделать по Вашему совету, но где-то есть упущение. Дополнил вопрос с пошаговым описанием выполненного, но где-то закрались неправильные действия или неполные

Comment: Скорее всего вы указали AnyCPU как целевую платформу. Для этой платформы нет описанных conditions. Вам надо добавить конкретные платформы x64 и x86 и собирать под какую-то из них. Если надо под AnyCPU, то смогу помочь ближе к понедельнику. Не очень удобно писать с телефона.

Comment: ок, доживём до понедельника